# isNaN not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, nan, numerical

I have a textbox setup the following way:

```
<input type="text" name="CardNumber" id="CardNumber" maxlength="7" onkeypress="if(isNaN(this.value+String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode))) return false;" onblur="ValidateCardNumber()"/>
```

(note: ValidateCardNumber() is a separate function that checks the length among other things, but it isn't part of limiting the field to numerical values).

This works fine in IE.  It will allow me to enter numbers but ignores a non-numerical keypress.

In Firefox, it I can't enter anything into that textbox.

Any thoughts?

I'm open to a different means to the end.

Thanks.

Comment: As with most such solutions, this is going to break horribly regardless if the user decides to paste in any text. Allow free input; validate afterwards and provide a `pattern` attribute on the `<input>`.

Comment: @epascarello: Why would `event` be a problem? The handler that's created and assigned to the element will have an `event` parameter in Firefox.

Comment: @cookiemonster It's something about `event.charCode`, `event.keyCode` and `event.which`.

Comment: @cookiemonster Does my answer below show you why the event is wrong.

Comment: @epascarello: `event` isn't wrong, as your answer shows.

Comment: The use of event was wrong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debugging will show you the problem

```
console.log(this.value+String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));
```

looking at the console you would see

[image]

So now look at what it is returning

```
console.log(this.value, event.keyCode);
```

[image]

So the key code is always returning zero.

What you need to do is use `event.which` for firefox

```
console.log(this.value+String.fromCharCode(event.which || event.keyCode));
```

[image]

Comment: works like  a charm.  Thanks!
Here's the revised code:
    onkeypress="if(isNaN(this.value+String.fromCharCode(event.which || event.keyCode))) return false;"